# Apache Camel: usage of ValueBuilder.convertTo in mock endpoint expectations

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, apache-camel

I cannot figure out how to use `ValueBuilder.convertTo` as a clause in Apache Camel's mock endpoint expectations. For some reason the expectations containing `convertTo` are ignored.

Here's a test that illustrates the issue:

```
package wheleph;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ConvertToTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    private static final String INBOUND_ENDPOINT = "direct:inbound";
    private static final String OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT = "mock:outbound";

    @Test
    public void testConvertToBody() throws InterruptedException {
        MockEndpoint mockOutboundEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT);
        mockOutboundEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockOutboundEndpoint.message(0).body().convertTo(String.class).isEqualTo("Blah");

        template.sendBody(INBOUND_ENDPOINT, "Message 1");

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(INBOUND_ENDPOINT).
                        to(OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The test case above should fail because the mock endpoint actually receives a message with body "Message 1" which is not equal to the expected value "Blah". However this test is green.

But if I remove `convertTo` from the mock endpoint setup (`mockOutboundEndpoint.message(0).body().convertTo(String.class).isEqualTo("Blah")`)
then the test fails as it should.

Am I using `ValueBuilder.convertTo` in a wrong way or is this a bug in Apache Camel testing framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide the type as a parameter to body, as shown:

```
mockOutboundEndpoint.message(0).body(String.class).isEqualTo("Blah");
```

Comment: Thanks, Claus. It works if I want to assert the message body. But what's if I want to assert a property value?

Also what is a purpose of ValueBuilder.convertTo?

Comment: There is a .header and .property also I think.

Comment: Correct, but unlike with AssertionClause.body, there are no overloaded methods "property" or "header" that accept the class to convert to (http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.13.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/mock/AssertionClause.html). Am I missing something?

Comment: The question raised in my previous comment has been reported: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7767